# Carregando duas classes com mesmo nome

Tags: php

Em um sistema legado, tenho situação que 2 classes possuem o mesmo nome. Uma versão legada e outra recente (usando framework MVC). Há casos que na versão nova da classe eu precise chamar a mesma (antiga) ou outra classe do sistema antigo. Infelizmente não há como eliminar a classe antiga (para manter compatibilidade) e seria muito complicado migrar para a versão nova, tendo que manter a nova e a antiga. O sistema velho não foi projetado para chamar métodos da nova, somente a nova consegue chamar a velha.

Após discussão, acabamos optando em criar uma classe que sirva de "ponte" para as classes antigas do sistema. Queríamos criar uma espécie de "sandbox", onde podíamos chamar classes velhas (com o mesmo nome que as novas) e retornar seus resultados, isoladamente.

Algo que resolveria (e seria o correto) seria utilizar `namespaces`, mas barra no problema do retrabalho de adequar tanto o velho como a nova parte. Então descartamos isso.

Acabamos injetando um __autoload() personalizado quando invocamos essa classe de "ponte". Onde verificar se o nome chamado existe na parte velha do sistema, se existir, pega o conteúdo dela, dá um *append* no nome dela, para modificar o nome e não causar conflito, verifica no código da classe e faz substituições de nomeclatura de outras classes para garantir que tudo dependente seja invocado. O conteúdo é salvado em um arquivo temporário e incluído, após o término é apagado o arquivo temporário.

Acho que vendo a classe vão poder entender melhor: https://gist.github.com/juliovedovatto/559eb1d76c4ea8fb81d8

Quero saber se existe uma forma mais eficiente de fazer isso, sem apelar para um hack do sistema. Vimos sobre o php `Runkit_Sandbox` (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/runkit.sandbox.php) e o `uopz` (http://php.net/uopz), mas nem imagino como se usaria isso (e se realmente dá certo). Temos outro problema que a versão do nosso PHP é 5.3 (infelizmente é trabalhoso atualizarmos versão, por causa do sistema legado).

Comment: Não poderia aplicar namespace?

Comment: Você pode usar namespaces somente na versão nova e chamar as classes com mesmo nome do namespaces raiz como uma dependência.

Answer (score 1):

Primeira opção, faça isso no deploy em vez de fazer um loader. É mais fácil e eficiente seu script de deploy fazer este renomeamento de classes uma vez só e só escolher o arquivo PHP.

Runkit em produção é uma má ideia.

Qualquer outra solução (exceto refatorar) vai ainda ser pior -- e eu recomendaria totalmente um refactoring. Note, se você só precisa alterar nomes de classes você consegue fazer um `sed` ou replace no seu próprio IDE com um regex, igual ao que você já colocou no seu autoloader, e resolver isso eternamente. Só vai ter problemas se o código abusar de evals, e você vai detectar qualquer problema na hora quando rodar sua suíte de testes.